# class does not implement ActivityResultLauncher AS ArcticFox

Tags: android-studio

I just installed the last version of  Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 3.

When I open my projects, studio shows error for all of the fragments :

```
Class 'MapsFragment' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun <I : Any!, O : Any!> prepareCall(contract: ActivityResultContract<I!, O!>, callback: ActivityResultCallback<O!>): ActivityResultLauncher<I!> defined in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

is it AS bug?

Comment: I believe it's just the IDE is being buggy as it's still Canary, but when I built and ran the app it worked fine and ignored this compile error :)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this problem happens after core-ktx version 1.3.0-rc01.
You can manage to solve it either by:
downgrading your core-ktx.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0-rc01'
```

or just add the suitable dependency for the fragment and leave your core-ktx as is

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-rc02'
```